# Why does the ld terminate with exit code -1?

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I have installed MinGW through MSYS2 and it worked fine until recently.
Lately on all of my compilations it gives me this message:

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file

Starting build...

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\*USER*\Documents\GitHub\Repo\ProgettoLista\ListaOggetti.cpp -o C:\Users\*USER*\Documents\GitHub\Repo\ProgettoLista\ListaOggetti.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\*USER*\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHqtMdU.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\*USER*\Documents\GitHub\Repo\ProgettoLista/ListaOggetti.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Persona::setNome()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\*USER*\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHqtMdU.o: in function `nodo::nodo()':
C:\Users\*USER*\Documents\GitHub\Repo\ProgettoLista/lista.h:14: undefined reference to `Persona::Persona()'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I have numerous times uninstalled MinGW and MSYS2 and the result is the same.

I have tried a Hello World and it works, but on most if not all cases it gives me the same error.

For instance, the code I am trying to compile is on three files.

1. Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista.h"

int main() {
    lista testa = NULL;
    lista nuovoNodo = NULL;
    nuovoNodo = new nodo;
    testa = nuovoNodo;
    nuovoNodo->prev = NULL;
    nuovoNodo->nome.setNome();
    nuovoNodo->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

2. Header

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Persona {
    public:
        Persona();
        string getNome();
        void setNome();
    private:
        string nome;
};

typedef struct nodo {
    struct nodo* prev;
    Persona nome;
    struct nodo* next;
} nodo;

typedef nodo* lista;
```

3. CD

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lista.h"

Persona::Persona() {
    nome = "a";
}

string Persona::getNome() {
    return this->nome;
}

void Persona::setNome() {
    cout<<"Inserisci il nome della persona: ";
    cin>>this->nome;
}
```

I have tried compiling from Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, MSYS2 console, dev c++ and they all give the same results.

The only exception is onlinegdb, which leads me to believe my problem is local.

Comment: You list 2 .cpp files but I only see one being compiled and linked in the build output. Just because you include the header file in a .cpp file doesn't mean the .cpp file containing its definitions will be automatically included.

Comment: Could it be that you don't give both source files to the compiler, one containing `main()`, one containing the implementation of `Persona`? In you g++ call you only seem to pass ListaOggetti.cpp

Comment: Look at the first line of the error, not the last one: ```undefined reference to `Persona::setNome()'```.